# Should I enable or disable upside down in my iOS app?

Tags: ios, xcode, orientation, screen-orientation

I made an iOS app with some web views an a contact page. You can navigate by using the toolbar on the bottom. I enabled landscape and, of cause portrait mode.

Should I enable upside down in my iOS app, too? Ore should i rather disable it? What is more user-friendly? What do you prefer?

Comment: I have never seen iPhone apps upside down.. seen a lot in iPad.However I voted to close the question.

Comment: I don't think this is really relevant for StackOverflow as this is not a programming problem. This would maybe be a better fit for https://ux.stackexchange.com/ but no guarantees.

Comment: Does anybody know, why there are no (iPhone) apps with upside down?

Answer (score 2):

If your app contains web views and contact pages then you should probably not enable upside down as it may not be user-friendly and cause inconvenience to the user while receiving calls, etc.

However, *music* and *voice memo* seems to be some situations where Apple saw fit to enable upside down. The reason is:

**1.Voice Memos:** Since the main microphone is on the bottom of the device, this app decides to allow this seemingly taboo orientation and kindly rotates the interface for you.

**2.Music**: It seems to be another case where Apple saw fit to allow an upside down orientation, but only if your device is plugged into, and playing music through, something like a car stereo. Maybe Apple accommodated for that kind of situation where the device often needs to be placed in a strange orientation in order to fit into a car setup.

Check [this](http://finertech.com/blog/featured/iphone-voice-memos-app-upside-down) for reference.

There are also some apps which support upside-down texting. Go through the [link](http://appcrawlr.com/ios-apps/best-apps-upside-down-text) for details.

So, it entirely depends on the functionality of your app to decide whether upside-down should be enabled or not. You can provide the use of your app to get more precise answers.

Answer (score 2):

The **upside down orientation** on iOS was introduced mainly for **iPad apps**, where it's more common open an app with the device rotated of 180°.

So **if your app support iPad you should enable this orientation**. As confirmation in [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1588/_index.html) you can read:

> Important: It is strongly recommended that your iPad applications
>   support all orientations. This includes portrait, portrait
>   upside-down, landscape left and landscape right. iPad apps that
>   require an orientation must support both variants of that orientation.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Yes, my app supports iPad, too. On iPad it should be enabled, I know. But on iPhone? Should it be enabled on iPhone, too?

Comment: Just enable on all devices. However you can eventually disable on iPhone if it makes some problems, it depends on your app.

Comment: It makes no problems. Are there any reasons against upside down?